# Is someone porting ubuntu one and software center for derivatives?

Tags: ubuntu-one, software-center, 12.04, derivatives

Since 12.04 is just around the corner, and the two main applications IMO right now are the USC and U1. Due to that, is there any plan to port them completely into Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu (also Ubuntu Studio.. but i think it's already there..)?

I think it will add the much-needed Ubuntu touch to those derivatives, so that they'll have their own personality.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [Lubuntu Software center](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/install-lubuntu-software-center.html) available:

[image: Lubuntu SC]

Kubuntu uses the Muon Suite as it's software center

[image: Kubuntu]

Xubuntu does have the Software Center aswell.

[image: Xubuntu]

(This is probably not the latest Xubuntu, but as you can see it runs the Software center too).

Comment: all these i know, and that doesn't answer my question :) i simply wish to know if USC itself can be imported (because i'm using Kubuntu 11.10 as well - and it doesn't really work..)

Comment: Why porting it when something for the designated derivatives already exists?..

Comment: Anyhow,the  USC uses GTk so it works in XFCE and LXDE without a port of any sorts, in KDE it will simply look out of place.

Comment: That's the whole idea. Instead of calling it "Muon" - why not port USC itself to KDE libs and voilà - there you have it. Same - btw - goes to Xubuntu (which proves my point) and Lubuntu - and i haven't even mentioned U1

Comment: Because it's not just "port it to KDE libs", look at the state of Ubuntu One KDE,it's pre alpha and it's advancing rather slowly.

Comment: Oh and the Xubuntu Software center it's not a port it's the same USC it just works and Lubuntu doesn't need one someone else rather than canonical created it, and Kubuntu is supposed to stay Vanilla KDE that's why you don't see  firefox, thunderbird, etc. there.